# Entering in Percent Under Const

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How exactly am I supposed to do this? `Const cdecTax As Decimal = 7.75%`I have tried putting it in decimal form (0.0775) and have tried rounding it, but the rounding doesn't work!

```
Private Sub lblFinalCostResponse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblFinalCostResponse.Click

    intFinalPrice = Format(Round, "0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: several things.  Round is a reserved word, so you probably don't have a variable named that.  Also, based on the "int" in intFinalPrice, I assume it is an integer, and your variable will round, but then it will be truncated when it is implicitly converted to the integer.  I think we need to see more of your code, and your variable declarations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit difficult to give you an exact answer as you haven't really posted enough code. But I assume you want to calculate the sales tax and return the final price of an item so I think something like this should do it:

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    Debug.WriteLine(CalculateFinalPrice(CDec(13.3445)))
End Sub

Private Const cdecTax As Decimal = 0.0775D
Public Shared Function CalculateFinalPrice(costPrice As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return costPrice + (costPrice * cdecTax)
End Function

Output:
14.37869875
```

Comment: Decimal literlas can be written with a 'D' suffix.  No need for the CDec.      Private Const cdecTax As Decimal = 0.0775D

Comment: @dbasnett - agreed but it doesn't make any difference to a `Const`